# How to access HTML elements using chrome extension/plugin?

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am experimenting with Chrome Plugin. I am trying to find all `<p>` tags on the html page and change the `font-family`/`size`/`color` of these tags. Basically I am just experimenting with this.

Here is what I have made so far.

A. manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "ABC XYZ",
    "description": "La la la...",
    "version": "1",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "ABC",
        "default_icon": {
            "19": "icons/logo.png"
        },
        "default_popup": "mydefault.html"
    },
    "manifest_version": 2
}
```

B. mydefault.html

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#do-magic").click(function() {
                // do something here with the page html.
                // change font-family
                $("body").append("test");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <span id="do-magic">Start</span>
</body>

</html>
```

When packed and loaded to chrome this works except the click event where I am trying to access the page elements.

[image]

The click event does not work. Nothing gets printed in console too.

Please advice.

Comment: No. I don't know what you mean by that ? Its present in the mydefault.html page that is opened when you click on the extension button on chrome. Its there on the DOM since then.

Comment: Try writing your `<script></script>` after `</body>` and see what is happening!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use inline scripts in Chrome Extensions, as per Content Security Policy. That's why your code does not get executed.

You have to move it into a separate file. See [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution).

Comment: You should also be aware that you're possibly looking for errors/output in the wrong console. You need to right-click the button and select "Inspect Popup" to access the right console.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to read current page contents you must use content scripts

Take a look at this
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

Check this example too

Example Description:https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#download-selected-links

Example Download:https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/downloads/download_links.zip